# Populating a slave table with only related to master table rows

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, relationship, sqldataadapter

Lets say that I have a huge table of orders and another a much bigger table of order details.

I have a `DataSet` which is being populated from two `SqlDataAdapter`s. The first one selects the orders for a specified customer. The second should select the order details of the orders of the specified customer(that are being selected by the first `SqlDataAdapter`). But I can't find a way to do this elegantly. When I'm adding the relationship I'm getting an error saying that 'This constraint cannot be enabled as not all values have corresponding parent values'.

I don't want to disable the constraint creation when creating the relationship, I also don't want to select all the rows of the second table. Is there a proper way of doing that? Or the only way is to build the SQL statement using f.e. `IN` clause? Now, as I figured out, it doesn't matter if I add this relationship before populating the tables or after, I'll get this message when adding the relationship after the tables were populated or when populating the second table in case the relationship was added prior to the data population.

### Code Example:

```
System.Data.DataSet dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
String connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection dbCon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ordersAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM dbo.Orders Where CustomerId={0}", customerId), dbCon),
                                     detailsAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.OrderDetails", dbCon); //Perhaps, I should change this to select only the rows needed, or shouldn't specify SQL at all since it should get all the related rows...

try
{
     dbCon.Open();

     ordersAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Orders");
     detailsAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "OrderDetails");

}
catch (Exception e)
{
     Response.Write("Database error: " + e.Message);
}
finally
{
     dbCon.Close();
     dbCon.Dispose();
}

dataSet.Relations.Add("Orders2Details", dataSet.Tables["Orders"].Columns["Id"], dataSet.Tables["OrderDetails"].Columns["OrderId"]/*, false*/); //I don't want to use this false
```

Comment: Let's have a look at the code. Presumably each order detail must have a parent order, so were all the data correct, such a relationship would work. Is the relationship applied to the correct columns, are they both non-nullable etc. etc.?

Comment: @barrick, sure, each order detail must have a parent order, but I'm selecting only the orders of a specified customer not all the orders what makes the select order detail without a `Where` clause unusable.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the `DataRelation` can't be added between the two tables within the `DataSet`, if the first table has all the orders for a person and the second has all the order details for those orders. If both have e.g. an `OrderID`, then it would suggest that there's something wrong with either the way in which the data is stored or the way it is being retrieved. Can you show an example?

Comment: @barrick, please have a look, not sure that it could be compiled though, the idea should be clear.

Comment: Okay, I see. The answer given looks to be what you want; I didn't realise that you'd not got just the order details for the customer's orders.

Comment: @barrick, sorry, what answer?

Comment: There was one there before! One second...

Answer (score 2):

You need to populate the `DetailsAdapter` with the relevant order details for the customer; only then can you create the relation between the two.

So, something like

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.OrderDetails INNER JOIN dbo.Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderID =
Orders.OrderID WHERE Orders.CustomerId = ...
```

will do.

However, don't do that with your queries in reality. Use stored procedures (the query is compiled on the db server, so performs much better), or, if you must use inline SQL, use the `SqlParameter` class to avoid SQL injection.

There might be nothing stopping me from providing

```
'1;DROP TABLE Orders;'
```

as the value for the customer ID I want to search for, and when appended into your query, it becomes something you really don't want to execute.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I'm aware of it, it's not a real code you know:) In real tasks I use `SqlParameter`s if the input comes from the user... I hoped though that there is a neat way to perform this kind of tasks, perhaps using some kind of dotNet's inner wheels, without all the hassle with handwriting the SQLs...